# Group by value for Map

Tags: java, java-8

If I have this map

```
Map<String,String> m2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    m2.put("2018-02-01", "0");
    m2.put("2018-02-02", "0");
    m2.put("2018-02-03", "1");
    m2.put("2018-02-04", "2");
m2.put("2018-02-05", "2");
```

Can I change this map to a group list by steam? Like this

```
Map<String,List<String>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on whether you want to group based on `key` or `value`, you can interchange in below code to `groupby`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
    m2.put("2018-02-01", "0");
    m2.put("2018-02-02", "0");
    m2.put("2018-02-03", "1");
    m2.put("2018-02-04", "2");
    m2.put("2018-02-05", "2");

    Map<String, List<String>> mapList = m2.entrySet().stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
    System.out.println(mapList);
}
```